# Windows: slow-motion in different soft programs (Video player, MS Word, MS Powerpoint)

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, video

After Windows reinstallation I faced a problem.
When I use different programs they work improperly:

- KMPlayer: when I play some video in plays in slow-motion (not related to the player's settings).
- When I use MS PowerPoint and do smth. in it (move objects, type text field, e.t.c) it reacts with delay. Also like in slow-mo.
- When I use MS Word and type text it shows up with some delay.

When I use different video player (original Windows app - "Movies and TV") videos play properly without delays).
When I use standard Windows text editor (Notepad) it works correct and symbols occur instantly. No delay.

Before reinstallation I used **Windows 10 Pro** edition and it worked correctly (I didn't install any videocard drivers or directX libraries; it just worked from a box). Since it has problem with specific applications and work correctly with built-in apps I don't think that problem is in videocard driver).

- Current Windows version: **Windows Home edition x64**.
- My PC: **Lenovo c560**

How can I resolve this issue?